# Why doesn't my VBA code work when the selection starts with a dot?

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I've created this code that is supposed to replace the commas in a selection with dots if there are any. The code, however, doesn't work if the selection starts a cell containing a dot, but it works if it starts with a cell containing a comma. It even works if it starts with a comma, then a cell with a dot and then again a cell with a comma. Here is the code:

```
Public Sub DeleteDotsReplaceCommasWithDots()
        
For Each cell In Selection

    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ".") > 0 And InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ",") > 0 Then
        Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    ElseIf InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ".") = 0 And InStr(ActiveCell.Value, ",") > 0 Then
        Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormul
    End If
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

Any idea about why this is happening? Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm under the impression that you loop through all selected cells, yet, on each loop, your conditions are based on the active cell and you replace in the selection as a whole. Also, I think `xlReplaceFormul` in the last `Replace` function is a typo...

Comment: Hey Victor, thanks for your answer. I fixed the typo. I also changed the "Selection.Replace" with "ActiveCell.Replace", but I still can't get the code to work when a cell with a dot in it is the first cell.

Comment: `ActiveCell` will not solve the problem, since it does not change for each iteration of the `For Each cell In Selection` loop. Switch to `cell` maybe.

Comment: So I've understood the for each cell in selection wrongly, my bad! But thank you, when I changed it to cell, it worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running your search/replace on `ActiveCell`, rather than each cell you're cycling through with your `For..Each` loop. I've tidied it up slightly using the `With cell.. End With` block.

Try this:

```
Public Sub DeleteDotsReplaceCommasWithDots()
        
    For Each cell In Selection
        With cell
            .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            If InStr(.Value, ".") > 0 And InStr(.Value, ",") > 0 Then
                .Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
                .Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            ElseIf InStr(.Value, ".") = 0 And InStr(.Value, ",") > 0 Then
                .Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula
            End If
        End With
    Next cell

End Sub
```